# Order of appearance of distribution support in an i.i.d sequence

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability, order-statistics

Consider a discrete distribution $\mathcal{D}$ with probabilities $(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ over numbers $1, \ldots, n$. In a sequence of i.i.d. draws from $\mathcal{D}$, $X_1, X_2, \ldots$, let $X^{(i)}$ denote the $i$th unique number that is observed in the sequence (e.g., in $2,1,2,3,\ldots$, we have $X^{(1)} = 2$, $X^{(2)} = 1$, $X^{(3)}=3$).

Is there a nice way to characterize explicitly or bound the probability of a particular order of appearance of the support in an i.i.d drawn sequence, such as

$$ \mathrm{Pr}_{ \{ X_i \}_{i=1}^{\infty} \sim \mathcal{D}^{\infty}}(X^{(1)}=1, \ldots, X^{(n)}=n) \quad ? $$

Comment: The distribution of $\pi=(X^{(1)},\ldots,X^{(n)})$ is related to the coupon collector problem with unequal probabilities. (I think it is also called as the Plackett-Luce ranking model). It is possible to compute the probability as an explicit formula of $p_i$'s (for example, using the exponential race trick), but this formula is not simple enough to easily extract information on the asymptotic behavior of the distribution of $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will repost on cross validated for more visibility, I should clarify that my sequence is sampled until I've seen all of $X_1,...,X_n$ (please feel free to also repost your reply there).

Comment: "my sequence is sampled until I've seen all of ..." That's also what I understood. Anyway, for any permutation $\sigma$ on the $n$ items $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, we have \begin{align*}\mathbf{P}((X^{(1)},\ldots,x^{(n)})=\sigma)&=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{P}(X^{(i)}=\sigma(i)\mid (X^{(1)},\ldots,X^{(i-1)})=(\sigma(1),\ldots,\sigma(i-1))\\&=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{p_{\sigma(i)}}{\sum_{j=i}^{n} p_{\sigma(j)}}\end{align*}